# Вопрос по WordPress. Делаю менюшку администратора на JQuery, мешают стили темы

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Делаю менюшку администратора для гостей и пользователей. Пытаюсь добиться, чтобы загружаемые шаблоны тем не нарушали ни чего. Не выходит.
Пробовал загружать последними свои стили.
Пробовал all: initial; использовать, во всех своих классах.
Я PHP использую только для подключения плагина и вывода HTML, остальное на JS.
Уже подумываю и стили скриптом прописать.

Подскажите что нибудь.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте деактивировать мешающие стили и скрипты.

Если в деактивированных скриптах-стилях есть нужный код - можно перенести его ваши стили и скрипты при подключение

```
//стили
function project_dequeue_unnecessary_styles() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'bootstrap-map' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'bootstrap-map' );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'project_dequeue_unnecessary_styles' );
```

```
//скрипты
function project_dequeue_unnecessary_scripts() {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'modernizr-js' );
    wp_deregister_script( 'modernizr-js' );
    wp_dequeue_script( 'project-js' );
    wp_deregister_script( 'project-js' );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'project_dequeue_unnecessary_scripts' );
```

Comment: Спасибо. Деактивировать стили я не могу, но решение нашёл. Основные стили вывел при загрузке моего Jquery-файла, скриптом. Весьма компактно получилось. Кучу шаблонов попробовал, не съезжают.